# method inside a thread does not get called

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, serversocket, event-dispatch-thread

The method serverinititaor().initialize(5555) in serverinitiator class is not getting called in following code.

This method will launch a new frame for client on port 5555 for some function like send message or chat purpose.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            frame = new JFrame("client list");
        panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Refresh Client list");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if(success){
                JButton jb = new JButton("A new Client on port 5555");
                jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        new ServerInitiator().initialize(5555);
                    }
                });
                panel.add(jb);
                frame.revalidate();
                }

    }).start();
```

}

ServerInitiator.java

```
synchronized public void initialize(int port){

    try {            
        final ServerSocket sc = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());            
        drawGUI();


        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    Socket client = sc.accept();
                System.out.println("New client Connected to the server");

                new ClientHandler(client,desktop);
                } catch (IOException ex) {

                }
            }
        }).start();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please reply.

Thanks.

Comment: where is `serverinititaor().initialize(5555)`.

Comment: Did you even manage to get this to compile?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to apply the minimal changes that are necessary to make it compileable. The result is this class. For some mysterious reason, I called this class `ItDoesGetCalled`.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ItDoesGetCalled
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("client list");
                final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                JButton button = new JButton("Refresh Client list");
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        boolean success = true;
                        if(success){
                            JButton jb = new JButton("A new Client on port 5555");
                            jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                                    new ServerInitiator().initialize(5555);
                                }
                            });
                            panel.add(jb);
                            frame.pack();
                        }
                    }        
                });
                panel.add(button);
                frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

class ServerInitiator
{
    synchronized public void initialize(int port)
    {
        System.out.println("Here we go...");
    }    
}
```

However, I **strongly** recommend you to clean this up. What are all the threads intended for? At the moment, something like this should be sufficient:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ClientServerUI
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Client list");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel clientListPanel = new ClientListPanel();
        f.getContentPane().add(clientListPanel);

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class ClientListPanel extends JPanel
{
    ClientListPanel()
    {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        JButton refreshButton = new JButton("Refresh client list");
        refreshButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                boolean success = true;
                if(success)
                {
                    createNewClientButton();
                }
            }        
        });
        add(refreshButton);
    }

    private void createNewClientButton()
    {
        JButton newClientButton = new JButton("A new Client on port 5555");
        newClientButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                new ServerInitiator().initialize(5555);
            }
        });
        add(newClientButton);
        SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this).pack();
    }
}

class ServerInitiator
{
    synchronized public void initialize(int port)
    {
        System.out.println("Here we go...");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not allocate your UI outside the `Event Dispatch Thread` (EDT). On the other hand, keep the networking off the EDT. Note that Swing has a single threaded painting model. UI components allocation and their interaction must be done on EDT. Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

For best performance, all tasks on EDT should be brief.  Networking should be handled on a worker thread. Several options are: `SwingWorker`, `ExecutorService` or your own auxiliary threads. `SwingWorker` has a built-in mechanism to push updates on EDT. In case of `ExecutorService` you can use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` for that purpose, same with your own worker threads.